# What is the electrical conductivity of pool water?

Tags: electrochemistry, water, conductivity, electricity, electrical-properties

What is the electrical conductivity of pool water? I tried to find some information, unfortunately without success. I need to know it to make an underwater electronic project.

Comment: What does "pool water" mean? Water in a swimming pool? From where does that water come?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik - Thank you for your answer. Yes, water in a swimming pool, for instance in a water park. I know this kind of water is chlorinated, but I also read that other substances are used instead of chlorine. Because of that I ask about "pool water” not "chlorinated water". Could you help me to figure it out?

Comment: Depends on the pool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pH should be around 8.4 and the conductivity in the range of 2.5 - 3 mS/cm. The lower value is appropriate for freshly prepared water. The conductivity is used for the determination of TDS (total dissolved particles).

Comment: This is a fine answer in principle, and cheers to it, but again we'll recommend you ask on Engineering.SE so that you might get some grasp on the ways in which your system is going to change over time under these conditions.